# How to delete two element in array in the same time?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
let a = {"data": [1,2,4]};
```

I have tried to delete two element at the same time:

```
a.data.splice(0, 1);
a.data.splice(2, 1);
```

But second deling can not find index 2 bacause splice rebuilds indexes. How to fix it?

Comment: Either shift the index you want to delete by however many deletions already happened or go back to forth. An even better idea is to use `.filter` since you don't have to figure out how to handle this, however, you cannot modify the array in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start from the end to beginning of the array. In short start with the larger index. This keeps the the index pointing to the same element.

```js
let a = { data: [1, 2, 4] };

a.data.splice(2, 1);
a.data.splice(0, 1);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

After removing first element the remaining element will shift 1 index up. So you could try:

```js
let a = {"data": [1,2,4]};
a.data.splice(0, 1);// after this the data will have [2, 4]
a.data.splice(1, 1);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the first and last elements of an array, you can use respectively [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) :

```js
let a = {"data": [1,2,4]};

a.data.shift();
a.data.pop();

console.log(a);
```